# Report generation

Tags: python, report

I am writing a web app using TurboGears, and in that app the users must be able to generate different reports.
The data the reports need is stored in a database (MySQL).
The reports must be returned either as a easily printable html document, or a pdf file.

I have previously used jasper and iReport for creating the documents, but if I can avoid having to fire up Java to create the report I would be happy.

Ideally I would like to specify reports in a easily readable markup language and then just feed the template data with some kind of library that produces the report.

I gladly accept any kind of hints on how I should go about generating these reports!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build some fancy PDFs from Python with the [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/) toolkit.

Answer (score 5):

[Pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) is my favorite solution to your problem.

Comment: This is one of the cooler things I have seen done with Python.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer: the easily readable format you are looking for might be [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/). From there it is very easy to go to PDF, html, RTF, etc. etc.